# Using auxiliary schema on WSO2 5.3.0 Identity Server LDAP user creation

Tags: openldap, wso2-identity-server

I am using WSO2 Identity Server 5.3.0
Using an external LDAP based on OpenLDAP as secondary userstore 
The person class is eduPerson as it is specified on
https://www.internet2.edu/media/medialibrary/2013/09/04/internet2-mace-dir-eduperson-201203.html

The class is defined as auxiliary

When i am trying to add a user i get

[LDAP: error code 65 - no structural object class provided];

In the configuration

```
  <Property name="UserEntryObjectClass">eduPerson</Property>
```

The full trace is the following

```
Caused by: javax.naming.directory.SchemaViolationException: [LDAP: error code 65 - no structural object class provided]; remaining name 'uid=testy'
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.mapErrorCode(LdapCtx.java:3167)
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:3082)
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:2888)
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.c_bind(LdapCtx.java:423)
at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.ComponentDirContext.p_bind(ComponentDirContext.java:299)
at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.PartialCompositeDirContext.bind(PartialCompositeDirContext.java:217)
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager.doAddUser(ReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager.java:275)
... 71 more
```

Can anybody help on this?

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED

The solution was to add more UserEntryObject class using as separator character / as it is described on ReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager class

```
 protected BasicAttributes getAddUserBasicAttributes(String userName) {
        BasicAttributes basicAttributes = new BasicAttributes(true);
        String userEntryObjectClassProperty = realmConfig
                .getUserStoreProperty(LDAPConstants.USER_ENTRY_OBJECT_CLASS);
        BasicAttribute objectClass = new BasicAttribute(LDAPConstants.OBJECT_CLASS_NAME);
        String[] objectClassHierarchy = userEntryObjectClassProperty.split("/");
        for (String userObjectClass : objectClassHierarchy) {
            if (userObjectClass != null && !userObjectClass.trim().equals("")) {
                objectClass.add(userObjectClass.trim());
```